# Convert number from date field to text and populate picklist field using execute anonymous

Tags: apex, date

I'm updating data using execute anonymous (one-time update).  The business wants me to replace date fields with picklist fields under a custom object called Category.  The new picklist field should contain the month from the date field.

For instance, the example below. Start Date Old is the date field with a value of 12/1/2020. I am to update Start Date New with a value of December.  I have to do this for 4 fields.

> Start Date Old = 12/1/2020 (date field)
> Start Date New = December (picklist field)

So far I was able to do the following:

```
//get all category records with Acceptance Date, End Date, Start Date, Reset Date not null (date fields)
List<Category__c> listOfCategories = [SELECT id, Acceptance_Date_Old__c, Acceptance_Date__c,Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c,Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c,Reset_Date_Old__c,Annual_Category_Review_Start_Date__c,Annual_Category_Review_Start_Date_Old__c
                                     FROM Category__c
                                      WHERE Acceptance_Date_Old__c != NULL 
                                     OR Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c != NULL
                                     OR Reset_Date_Old__c != NULL
                                     OR Annual_Category_Review_Start_Date__c != NULL
                                     ];

system.debug('# of categories ' + listOfCategories.size());

for(Category__c c: listOfCategories){
    if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c != null){
        if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 1){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'January';
            
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 2){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'February';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 3){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'March';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 4){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'April';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 5){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'May';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 6){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'June';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 7){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'July';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 8){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'August';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 9){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'September';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 10){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'October';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 11){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'November';
        }
        else if(c.Acceptance_Date_Old__c.month() == 12){
            c.Acceptance_Date__c = 'December';
        }
        
    }
    
    if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c != null){
        if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 1){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'January';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 2){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'February';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 3){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'March';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 4){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'April';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 5){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'May';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 6){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'June';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 7){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'July';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 8){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'August';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 9){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'September';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 10){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'October';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 11){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'November';
        }
        else if(c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date_Old__c.month() == 12){
            c.Annual_Category_Review_End_Date__c = 'December';
        }
        
    }
    
}
update listOfCategories;
```

It works but only for 2 fields. There's got to be a better way.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the text name of a month based on a `Date` instance by converting it to a `Datetime` and formatting it with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

```
public static String getMonthName(Date value)
{
    return Datetime.newInstance(value, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).format('MMMM');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.....I'm getting an error message at the method System.TypeException: Invalid date/time: Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 GMT 2018.  Below is my code   ```public static String getMonthName(Date value)
{
    
    return Datetime.valueOf(value).format('MMMM');
}


system.debug('# of categories ' + listOfCategories.size());

for(Category__c c: listOfCategories){
    if(c.Reset_Date_Old__c != null){
        c.Reset_Date__c = getMonthName(c.Reset_Date_Old__c);
 }
}``` My apologies for the format.  I'm new to this website.

Comment: @Pearson `Datetime.valueOf()` can't take a `Date`, something that still boggles me to this day. Replacing that with `Datetime.newInstance(value, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0))` will make this approach work.

Comment: @DerekF that did it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Adrian's answer is definitely the way to go.

If, for some reason you don't want to use that approach (or if you occasionally enjoy finding other solutions/approaches) there are a few other ways to go about this.

One alternative approach would be to use a `switch` statement. It pretty much translates into the same if/else structure you have now, but saves some typing

```java
public static String getMonthName(Integer month){
    String monthName;
    switch on month{
        when 1 { monthName = 'January';}
        when 2 { monthName = 'February';}
        when 3 { monthName = 'March';}
        when 4 { monthName = 'April';}
        when 5 { monthName = 'May';}
        when 6 { monthName = 'June';}
        when 7 { monthName = 'July';}
        when 8 { monthName = 'August';}
        when 9 { monthName = 'September';}
        when 10 { monthName = 'October';}
        when 11 { monthName = 'November';}
        when 12 { monthName = 'December';}
        when else { monthName = null;}
    }
}
```

Since month names aren't going to change (at least I hope not), providing this functionality as a method makes a lot of sense (you want your code to be DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), as opposed to WET (Write Everything Twice)).

The other approach I have in mind is a way that we can eliminate the if/else structure entirely by using a `List` or `Map`. This can't be done all the time, but this is one of the times where we can use this approach.

```java
public static String getMonthName(Integer month){
    // This list could be initialized on a single line (or fewer lines)
    // Just writing this out on separate lines to help make a point
    List<String> monthNames = new List<String>{
        null,        // index 0
        'January',   // index 1
        'February',  // index 2
        'March',     // index 3
        'April',     // index 4
        'May',       // index 5
        'June',      // index 6
        'July',      // index 7
        'August',    // index 8
        'September', // index 9
        'October',   // index 10
        'November',  // index 11
        'December'   // index 12
    };

    // Ok, so we didn't _completely_ eliminate the if/else
    // Just a little data checking to avoid errors (though you may want
    //   to throw an exception so you get a helpful error message instead)
    if(month == null || month < 1 || month > 12){ return null; }

    // The integer month number can be used to index into a List
    return monthNames[month];
}
```

You could augment both approaches by using custom labels instead of string literals (which would help with internationalization).

Once again, Adrian's approach is the one you should use.